# Power BI architecture

Tags: powerbi

I need your help please .I'm working with Power BI but I haven't undestand how it work exactly and what it is,is power BI just a tool of visualisation or it is a whole plateform BI which contain his ETL,Datawarhouse,Olap engine ?can someone explain to me this point and give me an the equivalence of ETL,Datwaehouse ,olap in Power BI and tell me wehere the Data is stored inside it.Thanks

Comment: please read up on what PowerBI is here: 

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/

Comment: you can also watch the videos on Power BI here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCy--PYvwBwAeuYaR8JLmrfg

Answer (score 7):

Power BI is only a visualization tool to create reports and dashboards. It can connect with heterogeneous data sources to source data for its reports and dashboards. It can be understood as a Front end tool for sharing of business analytical information to a user or group of users across the organization. ETL, Datawarehouse and OLAP are not available in Power BI, you will have to use tools like SSIS and SSAS for it and then you can connect your OLAP cubes to power BI and create reports and dashboards.

Comment: I would say that Power BI is more than just a visualization tool. You can perform basic ETL and data manipulation all in the same tool which can be very convenient ...

Comment: @Niraj your answer needs to be updated :)